# Replacing the video driver when the current driver does not work at all

Tags: drivers, nvidia, video

I put Ubuntu 12.10 on an Inspiron 5150 with the NVidia GeForce FX5200.  It was fully operational with Windows XP Home when I started.  It now boots to a black screen with a mouse cursor.  I formatted and reinstalled with it connected to the Internet, same result.  When I tried failsafe video mode, that did not work either.

I understand that a new video driver is required and that it is available.  I cannot find any directions that work for how to change the video driver if your current video driver is not working at all.  I tried "sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates" but it says Cannot access PPA... please check your internet connection."  I have downloaded nvidia-173-updates_173.14.35-0ubuntu1_i386.deb, but I am not even sure if that is the right file.  Assuming that is the right file and I have it on a USB drive, can someone walk me through the process of installing the driver?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when recently upgraded my HP ProBook 5330m from 12.04 to 12.10 first and then to 13.04. While 12.04 and 12.10 was working fine, upgrade to 13.04 made it boot to black screen.

I was able to fix it with 1) boot in recovery mode first, than 2) select 'enable networking' and 3) open up root console and finally 4) install intel video drivers with *sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel*

In your case I guess step 4 should look like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libvdpau1 nvidia-common nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```